# MATLAB: Check for while loop divergence

Tags: matlab, loops, while-loop

I have piece of code with a while loop. This loop will diverge in certain conditions and thus will yield a infinite loop.

I want to check whether the loop is diverging and break the loop in an elegant and efficient procedure.

A solution to this is to check every output of the loop, save it, and compare it to the previously calculated loop output.

This is the code:

```
ai = 0; 
ai_old = 100;   
iteration = 0;
CDeff  = 0;

while abs(ai - ai_old)>2*10^-1                                               % Get induced angle of attack

    iteration  = iteration +1;
    ai_old = ai;

    Cleff = (Clp * cosd(ai)^2 + CDeff * sind(ai) )/cosd(ai);
    Veff = Vp/cosd(ai); 
    Re_eff = Reinf * Veff/Vinf * cp/c;
    Meff = Mp/cosd(ai);

if iteration ==1
    AFdata(:,2) = AFdata(:,2)/cosd(SweepQC);
end

        [~,a_eff,CDeff]  = obj.ConstantVortex(AFdata,[],Cleff,Meff);
        ai = -a_eff + (AOA + Twists(zz))/cosd(SweepQC);

end
```

Here, `ai` is calculated with the function `obj.ConstantVortex` and compared with the previous calculated `ai`. The while loop is terminated when the difference is small enough.

However, it can occur that the difference between the initial `ai` and calculated `ai` is increasing with every iteration.

How can I check this? and break the loop accordingly?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A typical solution for this situation is to store more previous values, and monitor the behaviour over time. So instead of `ai_old`, you would use:

```
ai = 0;
num_prev = 5;  % how many previous results to check
ai_prev = zeros(1,num_prev);
iteration = 0;

while abs(ai - ai_prev(end))>2*10^-1

    iteration = iteration+1;
    % your loop code goes here

    % now update the array of previous values
    ai_prev = circshift(ai_prev,[0 -1]);
    ai_prev(end) = ai;

    if iteration > num_prev && all(sign(diff(ai_prev)))
        % the slope of the previous five results is positive, so exit
        break
    end
end
```

You can change the number of previous results and use whatever function is appropriate to check for a break condition on the data in `ai_prev` for your computation. For example you might want to do some averaging on the previous results, or use a different function than `diff()`.

Comment: Hey there, ai_prev = zeros[1 num_prev];  this is an invalid Matlab command. Also, && all(sign(diff(ai_prev))) is not a correct definition for an if statement since it will just yield a number and not a condition.

Comment: @BalrajBoyal thanks for that; edited to fix typo with zeros(). The `all` statement does return a true/false condition, so the statement evaluates correctly.

Comment: @ Mhopeng, Oh sorry, I was unaware of that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to keep last differences or min differences and compare the current difference with that. For example you can have variable `ai_older` and use it. You can add

```
ai_older = 1000;
```

before your while loop and then have

```
ai_older = ai_old;
ai_old = ai;
```

and change `while` condition to

```
while abs(ai - ai_old)>2*10^-1 && abs(ai - ai_old) < abs(ai_old - ai_older)
```

Now you can avoid divergence. However, I'm not completely aware of your problem and not sure using `abs` is required or not.

As I previously mentioned, depending to your problem you may want to keep minimum difference till now and compare current one against that.

Comment: HI, should you also not define ai_old before the loop?

Comment: Definitely you need to define it before loop. Although, it is changing in each iteration, for first time entering the loop you need that.